Why is the status reset in Compose?
I am experiencing a very strange problem. I'm making a method to handle click events on the screen, as I want to save all the pointers in a map with their id and position, I have a state class in which I have this map and I'm updating it with a method in the ViewModel
data class RandomState(
    val touchedPositions: Map<Long, Pair<Float, Float>> = emptyMap(),
)

fun updateTouchedPositions(
    touchedPositions: Map < Long, Pair < Float, Float >> 
) {
    println("Function from viewModel: $touchedPositions")
    state = state.copy(
        touchedPositions = touchedPositions)
}

.pointerInput(Unit) {
    awaitEachGesture {
        val positions = mutableMapOf < Long, Pair < Float, Float >> ()

        do {
            val event = awaitPointerEvent()
            val canceled = event.changes.fastAny {
                it.isConsumed
            }

            if (event.type == PointerEventType.Press) {
                event.changes.forEach { pointer - >
                    val id = pointer.id.value
                    val x = pointer.position.x
                    val y = pointer.position.y
                    positions[id] = Pair(x, y)
                }
                println("Se van a guardar las posiciones: $positions")
                viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(positions)
                println("Posiciones de dedos en onPress: ${state.touchedPositions}")
            }

            if (event.type == PointerEventType.Release) {
                println("Posiciones de dedos en onRelease: ${state.touchedPositions}")
            }

        } while (!canceled)
    }
}

So I declare in my viewModel my state class which I access in the Composable with a viewModel.state.
// ViewModel class

var state by mutableStateOf(RandomState())
        private set

The problem is that although with the debug everything seems to be fine, when I'm in the second print inside the if of the do block, the state.touchedPositions is empty. It's as if the state class is somehow reset to the default state, but I'm not able to know why.

From the code you provided it is unclear what state is and how it happens to be accessible in pointerInput, so the following includes a bit of guess work.
pointerInput is a composable function, and composable functions are usually recomponsed when any state changes that they access. pointerInput, however, explicitly defines another behavior: Like remember or LaunchedEffect, it only recomposes when the key parameter(s) change. Since you provided Unit as the key, pointerInput will only be executed once, when the composable enters the composition. It then captures all variables that it needs in a closure. That is like a snapshot of all the objects that the variables currently contain. state is such a variable who's object will be captured, and that object will be used for everything that happens inside pointerInput (your log statements).
When the state variable changes (possibly due to recompositions), the closure will still only contain the initial object. And since you decided by using Unit to never recompose pointerInput, that closure will also never be refreshed with the current value. So whatever you do to the state in the view model, it will never reach the pointerInput lambda.
Long story short: You need to either replace Unit by state or move the log statements outside of pointerInput.

I mean, if for example inside pointerInput I am changing the state value of touchedPositions with the viewModel method and if I use this state as it is updating instead of Unit, it should update fine? Because I just tried it and it doesn't work

Should probably work, depends a lot on what state actually is in the view model, how compose receives updates of that variable and how that object is then passed around in compose. If all of this is done correctly, it should work, yes. Just put some more log messages in your code to track what state actually contains all the way from the view model to the pointerInput. Then it should become clear where it goes wrong.

No, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it still doesn't work, instead of Unit I put state.touchedPositions.size, so that every time the size changes it will recompose itself, but it doesn't, the logs inside pointerInput are still empty.

And all the other logs I talked about? Up until when does everything look ok, when does it go wrong?

I've put registers in both if and in the viewModel to see what I'm going to save before saving, and they all contain the correct values, but when I lift my finger, which is when the second if is executed inside pointerInput, the value of state.touchedPositions, is empty.

Yes, I know that. But that's not what I asked: "Just put some more log messages in your code to track what state actually contains all the way from the view model to the pointerInput". Please tell us the exact line of your code where your state variable first doesn't contain the expected value any more.

In the first if inside pointerInput, the second println, that value is no longer the one I expect.

If you keep your MutableState<RandomState> in the view model, try referring to it directly:
println("Posiciones de dedos en onPress: ${viewModel.state.touchedPositions}")

It is unclear how state in the composable derived from state in the view model, but I suspect the error hides there.

I don't think that's the fault, because in my Composable I already have a variable called state with the value viewModel.state.

You mean val state = viewModel.state? It's very different. @Ludiras

WTF, I tried it and you are right, why does this happen?

It captures the value of viewModel.state during the composition of the composable where you declare it and It won't update unless that composable recomposes. @Ludiras

So what you mean is that the value of state, which is clear in the variable above, is stored inside pointerInput and if nothing recomputes it, that value will always be that first value?

Yes, you could force recompositions by pointerInput(viewModel.state) to update a local state but it is unnecessary extra work. @Ludiras

"So what you mean is that the value of state, which is clear in the variable above, is stored inside pointerInput and if nothing recomputes it, that value will always be that first value?" -- That's what I said in my answer, actually. :)
